# In two AWS EC2 instance, three-js-fiber react app deploy, result is different from each instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to publish 2 three.js projects by using react-three-fiber.

But, we still have some issues.

We are using AWS two EC2 instance to deploy these demos, but two EC2 instance show different result.

One EC2 instance is showing so bright, and other one is showing so dark, but our source is perfectly same.

And EC2 instance type and nginx setting also almost same 99%.

We try to find the reason, but still... :(

Here is 2 demo addresses, and screenshot image.

Please help ㅠㅠ

(right image) base : http://3.36.99.191/dive

(left) test : http://13.125.197.254/dive

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be slightly different published versions.
Look at the source source HTML formatting and `bundle.js`

- http://3.36.99.191/bundle.js - Looks like prod deployment
- http://13.125.197.254/bundle.js - Looks like a dev deployment

I would check that first.